# 18.04 WiFi OK with mobile Hotspot, but doesn't work with my WiFi network

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

When I connect to my mobile Hotspot my internet works fine. But when I try to connect to my WiFi network it is very slow, some pages don't load and sometimes it even stops working after a few minutes. Do you have any idea what the problem is?

System:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

[nmcli d wifi Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yocgH.png) (The first one is my home network and Moto G is the mobile hotspot)

[WiFi Network: netstat -ie](https://pastebin.com/ib1KerXE)

[Mobile Hotspot: netstat -ie](https://pastebin.com/gPgDPH0E)

Comment: 1) which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and 2) which release number? 3) Please run _nmcli d wifi_ then highlight and copy the result,, click [edit] and add items 1-3 to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Done! I added the request data.